# Chrome issue with angled CSS gradient background

Tags: google-chrome, css

I'm having an issue with a CSS gradient background I have for an 100% width/height div. It's only a problem in Chrome. I have some content on top of the div, and when I hover over links in that div, the gradient background breaks in odd ways, and also doesn't display the angles basically at all (just appears as a horizontal gradient). Here's my css:

```
.landing{
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background: #f6e25a;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-80deg,#f6e25a 0%,#f6e25a 35%,#f8e979 35.01%,#f6e25a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#f6e25a), color-stop(35%,#f6e25a), color-stop(35.1%,#f8e979), color-stop(100%,#f6e25a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-80deg,#f6e25a 0%,#f6e25a 35%,#f8e979 35.01%,#f6e25a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-80deg,#f6e25a 0%,#f6e25a 35%,#f8e979 35.01%,#f6e25a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-80deg,#f6e25a 0%,#f6e25a 35%,#f8e979 35.01%,#f6e25a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(150deg,#f6e25a 0%,#f6e25a 35%,#f8e979 35.01%,#f6e25a 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6e25a', endColorstr='#f6e25a',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Here's what it looks like in Chrome:

[image]

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Chrome. It was first noted in November 2012, and is currently priority 2, so might not be fixed in the next release. See the Chromium dev forum [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162538)

If you change your angles ever so slightly, it should work again. Try using -78deg rather than -80deg